# Microsoft Graph API Create Device | Correct deviceID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

We're trying to automate device creation using the Graph API.

What is our situation: We don't have intune. We use another 3rd party MDM solution and have a API there to extract information. We have Azure and we use conditional access to allow access to cloud ressources from managed and compliant devices only.

So far only Intune can report compliance status to Azure AD of a managed iOS device. So we were trying to automate ths process by creating devices in Azure AD using Graph API and stuck on the value to use for `deviceID` in the JSON ([documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/device_post_devices)).

The general `UUID` and `UDID`, what we can get from our MDM API are not working, so the device is not recognized because the `deviceID` read from the OneDrive App for example is not matching with `UUID`/`UDID` we extracted, during authentication in Azure as compliant/managed.

Can anyone help how to correctly generate/use the Create Device API in Graph to have the right `deviceID` so the device will be recognized correctly when accessing cloud resources?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Statements like "The general UUID and UDID, what we can get from our MDM API are not working" doesn't provide enough detail. How is it not working? What error are you getting?